# Why is my pecan tree only producing tiny fruits?

Tags: diagnosis, tree-care, nutrients, hot-weather, pecan

For a couple of years, my pecan tree has been yielding tiny nuts (3 cm/1 inch in length), and only a few of them.

I live in a Mediterranean climate, and the last few summers were somewhat harsher than the usual. Can this be the cause? Can it be nutrient deficiency?
The tree seems mostly healthy, and has been bearing fruits for a couple of decades.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem in zone 7 USA. I checked with the local agriculture guy and he said it was probably due to zinc deficiency. He advised applying zinc and 10-10-10 fertilizer in February. I did that and it seems to be helping. I picked up a bunch yesterday that Hurricane Matthew blew off this week and while green they were fully developed. I will continue with this feeding schedule from now on.